# what do these log entries mean?

Tags: networking, network-manager, whoopsie

Ubuntu 18.04

I see this happen several times each day:

```
May 24 23:16:36 servername NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1621916196.7265] connectivity: (eno1) timed out
May 24 23:16:36 servername NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1621916196.7265] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 24 23:16:36 servername dbus-daemon[894]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=936 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 24 23:16:36 servername whoopsie[1685]: [23:16:36] offline
May 24 23:16:36 servername dbus-daemon[894]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 24 23:16:36 servername nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
May 24 23:16:36 servername nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
```

Sometimes it looks like this:

```
May 24 23:26:07 servername NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1621916767.8146] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May 24 23:26:07 servername dbus-daemon[894]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=936 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 24 23:26:07 servername whoopsie[1685]: [23:26:07] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 24 23:26:07 servername whoopsie[1685]: [23:26:07] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 24 23:26:07 servername whoopsie[1685]: [23:26:07] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
May 24 23:26:07 servername dbus-daemon[894]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 24 23:26:07 servername nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
May 24 23:26:07 servername nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
May 24 23:26:08 servername whoopsie[1685]: [23:26:08] online
```

What is going on?  Why is my NIC (eno1) timing out?
"connected_site" versus "connected_global"???
"Not a paid data plan"?  Whaaaat?

Comment: The logs that you provided don't give us enough information. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `grep -i en01 /var/log/syslog*` (use paste.ubuntu.com if this output is large). Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, lswh -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qD2w7yChrN/

Comment: @heynnema > cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: @heynnema > cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            addresses: ['10.1.1.100/24']

Comment: @heynnema system obviously has 2 NICs, en01 is outward facing, connected to router and local ISP, enp2s0 internal facing on blind NW along with a bunch of video cameras.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, the grep shoulda been eno1 not en01, took me a few to figger that out.  eno1 is timing out often, according to logs.  /var/log/syslog:<br />May 25 00:11:36 servername NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1621919496.7020] connectivity: (eno1) timed out  
/var/log/syslog:May 25 01:11:36 servername NetworkManager[936]: <info>  [1621923096.7288] connectivity: (eno1) timed out  Do I have a hw problem?

Comment: You've obviously figured out that putting large amounts of data into comments makes an unreadable mess. That data should be added as an edit to your question, after pasting, select the pasted text, click on the {} icon to format it to human-readable. Is your eno1 port connected DIRECTLY to your router via a single cable? Is it a cat 5e or cat 6 cable? Change the cable and see if there's any improvement.

Comment: @heynnema eno1 is connected directly to router, which is connected to ISP provided router.  I will get the cable changed out.  The box is quite a ways away, so it will be a day or so before I can get there to swap it.  If that doesnt improve it, I will try an additional NIC and disable eno1.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Answer (score 3):

> "Not a paid data plan"? Whaaaat?

That one is simple: if the connection IS a paid data plan you would run out of Mbs pretty quickly. Whoopsie will NOT connect if you told the system not to use that connection if you pay for every Mb.

> "connected_site" versus "connected_global"???

There are 3 states:

- `state-connected-global` Indication that NetworkManager is connected to Internet.
- `state-connected-local` Indication that NetworkManager is connected to a local network.
- `state-connected-site` Indication that NetworkManager is connected to networks other than Internet.

> Why is my NIC (eno1) timing out?

That can be a lot of things: your ISP, your router. A broken NIC or not fully supported driver. But it could also be ANOTHER network that picked up your connection and that would then match your logs: that would be a `state-connected-site`. Worth investigating if that is the case: so have a closer look to for instance `ip link show` when this happens.

Comment: > ip link show
     1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:fd:08:70:21:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:f0:5d:98:b6:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: I obviously do not understand how the formatting works on these comments, apologies....thanks for the offers to help diagnose.

Comment: add it the question ;-)